# Haskell iterate lists by 4 elem

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

How I can iterate a list of elements four by four and then add these four card to a tuple?.

Basically this a function that receives the Suit that it was to be killed, the cards played by order and the player who has played first.

That game is played by pairs, so it returns a tuple with the cards won for the first couple and the cards won for the second couple.

```
winnedCards:: Suit-> [Card] -> Int -> ([Card],[Card])
winnedCards [] _ = ([],[])
winnedCards (Suit type) cardsPlayed positionFirstPlayPerson
 | snd(xs) == 3 = (take 4 (cardsPlayed),[])
 | snd(xs) == 1 = (take 4 (cardsPlayed),[])
 | otherwise = ([],take 2 (cardsPlayed))
 where xs = whoHasWon (take 4 (cardsPlayed)) (Suit type)
```

whoHasWon returns the position of the player who has won. I think I have to it recursevily because I have to iterate 4 by 4, and then add the result to the tuple after each iteration.

Comment: What do you mean with *add those four types to a tuple*? Furthermore the demonstrated sample does not look syntactically sound.

Comment: The function returns a tuple. The first element of the tuple are all the cards won by the second pair. The second element of the tuple are all the card won by the first pair. That's why I said "add"

Comment: But it is rather unclear when a card is won by a player. Based only on the first question, I think you want a function with signature `[a] -> [(a,a,a,a)]`, but then you show a function which seems to perform way too much work. Usually it is better to split the function into multiple small functions that each perform a specific and simple task.

Comment: No, because I received all the cards, not only 4 cards.

Comment: I see you are struggling with taking 4 at a time from a list from the beginning to the end of the list. Following is a general purpose function that converts a list into a list of lists of 4 elements each. The key is the splitAt function. I see you are using take. `splitAt` is just like `take` plus `drop` together.  `s4 [] = []; s4 l = (fst ss):s4 (snd ss) where ss = splitAt 4 l`

Answer (score 3):

As Willem Van Onsem mentions in the comments, your function appears to do entirely too much work. If you're trying to split a list into groups of four-tuples, do that separately from the rest of the logic.

```
toFourTuple :: [a] -> [(a, a, a, a)]
toFourTuple [] = []
toFourTuple (a:b:c:d:rest) = (a, b, c, d) : toFourTuple rest
toFourTuple _  = error "list not divisible by four"
                 -- how should this be handled?
```

For the rest, it might be useful to know that the Monoid instance of `Monoid a => (a, a)` implements `mappend` as `mappend (x, y) (x', y') = (x <> x', y <> y')`, so if you generate a list of `(leftside, rightside)` sublists, you can `mconcat` them together.

```
xs = [ ([1]   , [3])
     , ([2, 4], [5])
     , ([6]   , [7, 9, 11, 13])
     ]
mconcat xs = ([1,2,4,6],[3,5,7,9,11,13])
```

Of course this works incrementally too.

```
-- |Separates [Int] into ([odds], [evens])
splitByMod2 :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
splitByMod2 [] = ([], [])
splitByMod2 (x:xs)
  | odd x  = ([x], []) `mappend` splitByMod2 xs
  | even x = ([], [x]) `mappend` splitByMod2 xs
  | otherwise = error "This cannot happen"
```

Comment: In the second line, you should use round brackets, not square brackets I think.